# Ruby TK Combobox selection won't disappear

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

This is my code:

```
combobox = Tk::Tile::Combobox.new (root) {
  values ["Folders","Files"]
  state "readonly"
  grid "row" => 1, "column" => 0, "sticky" => "w"
}
```

After i select one of the values, i want the blue selection to go away.

[image]

So i tried to use this `combobox.selection_clear`, but it didn't worked at all. 
If i set the widget on 'normal' instead 'readonly', so this will work. But in normal state, the content of the combobox can be modified by the user and i want to avoid this, removing the blue selection too.

I tried also `TkSelection.clear(combobox)`, but it didn't worked too.

This is my ruby version:

```
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x64-mingw32]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if those methods won't work cause of a bug, but i found the solution..

I made a binding on a virtual event:

```
combobox.bind("<ComboboxSelected>") {combobox.selection_clear}
```

But this won't remove the blue highlightning as said in the question above.

Instead if i remove the focus from the combobox, and i set it on a frame or on another widget like this,

```
combobox.bind("<ComboboxSelected>") {combobox.selection_clear; frame.focus}
```

So the blue part will go away.. The pic above looks like this now:

[image]

Changing the focus with `frame.focus` made the trick.